# Combine the menu bar and the window frame in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a (custom) menu bar that is integrated with the (custom) window frame. An example of what I am trying to achieve is what VSCode has. 
[image: VSCode Menu]

The menu bar appears on the same row as the title and the window buttons. Take note of the customized window frame (or) and menu bar. The window buttons (- ☐ X ) keep the Windows 10 style.

I am trying to recreate this using JavaFX. First off, I can't tell if that's a custom frame, or a custom menu bar without a frame. Both would lead to different answers, so I just want to create something as similar to VSCode's in JavaFX.

So far, this is what I have.
[image: JavaFX window frame and menu bar]

*I don't want to have the window frame and the menu bar separated!* It takes up too much valuable space in my specific project. Besides, I like the dark theme instead of the default white window frame.

It would be nice to somehow edit the window frame to have a custom bar, but I don't think that is easily possible in JavaFX. Instead, I think I'm going to focus on making a custom menu bar with a frameless window. I can make a frameless window with: `myStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);`
With a frameless window, I loose the window mobility and resize, as well as the window title, icon and the Windows 10 window buttons. **Is there a way to implement these features to a custom menu bar, or to merge a menu bar and a window frame using JavaFX?**

Edit:
This is what I have so far. I took down the menu items, and I made the window frameless.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage window) {
    window.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

    Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");

    fileMenu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("New Project..."));
    fileMenu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Open Project..."));
    fileMenu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Exit"));

    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    menuBar.getMenus().addAll(fileMenu);

    BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();
    layout.setTop(menuBar);

    Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 500, 200);

    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();
}
```

Comment: no code snippets? i don't even know if you using fxml or pure javafx to create your app :0 Well yes if you use undecorated stage you will lose all that nice features (resize, dragAndDrop, etc), but you can write this features to your window with an addListener as well...its a bit of work, but there are already a lot of snippets which helps a lot! Regarding your color, you can use css or setStyle for your app, to create a dark theme :3

Comment: I was using fxml, but decided to just stick with plain javafx code. A note on the CSS, would it slow the Java application down?